# MySQL - Using * in a conditional statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I am attempting to execute the following statement...

```
SELECT
SUM(CASE WHEN CLG ='A*' THEN 1 END) as A*
From Grades
```

However, I receive the following error...

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*,"

I realise of course that * is used in select statements to select all the rows of a table. However in my case, I want to find the number of records that contain the value of A*. Would anyone be able to point out what I can do to solve this error without having to remove the A* values from my table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use backticks:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN CLG ='A*' THEN 1 END) as `A*`
From Grades;
```

Actually you could skip `CASE`:

```
SELECT SUM(CLG ='A*') as `A*`
From Grades
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the column alias.  Don't use inappropriate characters for column names.  Do something like this:

```
SELECT SUM( CLG = 'A*' ) as A_star
From Grades;
```

Having to deal with identifiers that use unusual characters is just a pain -- making queries hard to write and to read.